# Why you can't name constant fetch in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to JavaScript, I ran into an interesting issue, when I try to name a constant fetch I am not able to use it, I was wondering why? Isn't every declaration unique to the compiler?

example

```
export const fetch = async ( url , method ) => {
    const options = {
        method: method,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    try {

        const response = await fetch( url, options );
        return response.json();

    }
    catch ( e ) {
        throw e;
    }
};
```

Comment: I think it is because exports is a global object

Comment: What do you mean, you can't use it. Do you get any error?

Comment: Isn't fetch a reserved word now?

Comment: @Nick No, fetch is built in function and it can be used as variable name

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin But he has tried to define it as a function, so how will the runtime know if he wants to use his function or the built-in one?

Comment: @Nick I think, it will simply override default `fetch` function, so, if you not create reference to old `fetch` function, you can't use it

Comment: Please provide a complete example, how are you trying to use it? What you have given us is not a reproducible example.

Comment: @LuboAntonov its a function that returns  promise, I was trying to us the above example importing the function into another file, passing the arguments, then use .then() and .catch()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constant can have arbitrary name, as long as it consists of valid characters and is not a [reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/javascript-reserved-words).

Since `fetch` is local variable and shadows global `fetch`, `await fetch( url, options )` will result in recursive call of same local function - and will likely throw an error, because it never calls `window.fetch` (`global.fetch`), and there is no `response.json()`.

`fetch` variable name would be misleading, because it can be confused with global `fetch`, and it certainly shouldn't be used here, because global `fetch` is supposed to be used, too.